# I wanna send localhost:8000/accounts/detail ,but it cannot be done

Tags: python, django

I wanna send `localhost:8000/accounts/detail` ,but it cannot be done.
I wrote in views.py

```
def login(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if regist_form.is_valid():
        user = regist_form.save(commit=False)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'login_form': login_form,
            'regist_form': regist_form,
        }

        return HttpResponseRedirect('detail')

    if login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.save(commit=False)
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'login_form': login_form,
            'regist_form': regist_form,
        }
        return HttpResponseRedirect('detail')

    context = {
        'login_form': login_form,
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/login.html', context)
```

Now in the part of HttpResponseRedirect,it sends `localhost:8000/accounts/login/detail` so error happens.This page read login method is `localhost:8000/accounts/login`.I wanna send the url to `localhost:8000/accounts/detail`.So,how should I fix this?
In urls.py,I wrote

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^detail$', views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login,name='login'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the exact url path in **HttpResponseRedirect**

Try this:

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail'))
```

Reverse can be imported from **django.urls**

Or you could just use:

```
  from django.shortcuts import redirect
  #codes...
  return redirect('detail')
```